# Determine a basis of the $\mathbb{Z} / 3\mathbb{Z}$-vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I guys, I have this vector space:
$$V = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T ∈ (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^4 | x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = [0]\}$$
of this I have to determine a basis of the $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$-vector space $V$.
So my problem now is how to proceed to do this, because I don't know how to treat $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It's just the field with three elements $\{\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2}\}$ where the addition and multiplication are modulo $3$.

Comment: Maybe is a stupid question, but why three elements?

Comment: So you solve your equations in the usual Guassian way and get that the solutions are all $(-k-l-m,m,l,k)$ as $k,l,m\in\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: There are three elements in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, namely $\bar{0}=3\mathbb{Z}$, $\bar{1}=1+3\mathbb{Z}$, and $\bar{2}=2+3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Aah okay, I understand perfectly well, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the equation dictates that you can choose $x_1, x_2, x_3 $ to your liking, and $x_4 = -x_1 - x_2 - x_3$, Therefore every vector in V is of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
-x_1 -x_2 -x_3 \end{pmatrix} $. Can you find a basis now? not that there is nothing special about the field we are working over.